# Get single column from many-to-many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I created many-to-many relationship between **User** model and **Role** model with the pivot table `'role_user'`. I want to retrive a single column `'role_name'` for the authenticated user as an array.

Here's my configuration for User and Role model:

User.php:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

Role.php:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

AuthController.php:

```
public function details()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user['role'] = $user->roles;
    return response()->json(['success' => $user], 20);
}
```

To which laravel responds with the following:

```
{"user":{"id":4,"first_name":"Jill","last_name":"mclane","email":"jill@g.co","role":[{"id":1,"role_name":"vendor","pivot":{"user_id":4,"role_id":1}}]}}
```

I want to get `role_name` column as an array for a selected user. eg. `role:['vendor','admin']`. I used `select` method but it returns `pivot` along with other columns:

```
$user['role'] = $user->roles()->select('role_name')->get();
//returns {"user":{"id":4,"first_name":"Jill","last_name":"mclane","email":"jill@g.co","role":[{"role_name":"vendor","pivot":{"user_id":4,"role_id":1}}]}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pluck` method on the Collection to do this:

```
$user['role'] = $user->roles->pluck('name');
```

You have loaded the `roles` relationship when accessing `$user->roles` though. Though it is not showing in your current output.

This method also exists for Query Builder.

```
$user['role'] = $user->roles()->pluck('name');
```

This would not load the relationship.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck) `pluck`

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Queries - Retrieving Results - Retrieving A List Of Column Values](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results) `pluck`

Answer (score 0):

An easy and good way to approach something like this would be to use API resources. That way you can customize the JSON response from the controller.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources

Answer (score -1):

use `first()` function to get single record

```php
$user['role'] = $user->roles()->first()->role_name;
```